# Single table or multiple tables for intensive updates on rows?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design

I'm moving a Nosql analytics system to SQL for better query and scalability. I have about 2000 accounts.

For each account I track various metrics, that are in total 500-3000 rows per day (for each account).
Each row has a value column that's intensively updated (increment, set) with incoming real-time event data. All others are indexes.

The updates are currently at about 300-400 / minute and not sure how I can optimize them.

```
account_id
type
date
resource_id
key
value
```

My question is: best approach is to have one huge table with account_id as part of the index OR separate tables with identical structure?

I was thinking of getting a postgreSQL, but can go with Mysql as well if that would be worth.

Comment: Don't guess or ask random people on the internet for their guesses- try you actual workload on some actual hardware. Start simple and see if your (frankly tiny) number of updates causes you any problems. Then come back with a detailed question if you have one.  Tip: "fillfactor" might be a useful search keyword for postgresql at least.

Comment: For MySQL:  7 Inserts/updates per second is no problem.  1000/second _might_ be a problem.  If you are having trouble, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the query.

Comment: Also, how long will the data be collected?  That sounds like a billion rows per year; let's review the schema for shrinking datatypes.  Will you be purging "old" data?  Let's plan for that _now_.  What `SELECT` queries will you do?  Maybe we need to discuss "summary tables".  More on sensor collection:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_sensor .

Comment: @RickJames I'm storing them for 3 years as I plan to add projections. Purging happens in the meantime, when client leaves. I decided to go with multiple dbs/tables

Comment: "Purge by client" -- Big deletes:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Comment: "multiple dbs/tables" -- How often do you need to perform a query that spans multiple clients?

Comment: @RickJames never between clients. That's why I'm 95% inclined to make siloes per client

Comment: That sets you up for "sharding" -- multiple machines, each with multiple clients.  But the metrics you provided imply that the system is a long way from being too busy for a single server.

Comment: that helps. I simply thought 300/400 updates per minute is a lot as well as 6M rows per day. Now I'm more relaxed that understood this is not a problem. And was looking to be prepared for growing it * 5.